# Code not executing when placed in separate test classes

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, page-factory

I am wring a `PageFactory` framework for a website using maven+TestNG,
I have page wise `PageObject` classes where all web elements and actions specific to page are present like `LoginPageObject`, `AccountSelectionPageObject`...
I have a class "Base" where the common elements like WebDriver, Logger are present.
I have a class "BasePage" where the common actions like click, scroll, select, refresh... are present

MyTestng.xml is having separate `<class>` entry for both all individual pages.
It's just that I am initializing the browser object in `@BeforeSuiit` and stored/placed it in the Base class which is being extended in my Test classes
Below is the flow/arch I came up for my project.
 [image]
**Issue:**

I have multiple @Test in each of my test classes.
When my Test classes are executed individually, all @Test script executed,
but when I execute them continuously, i.e. my testng file have separate entries for all my test classes, my execution fails. Error says unable to find element on page, I have wait statements, but still it's not working.

I have tried debugging code, but not able to find the reason as the flow stops on starting of second page with exception saying element not found

Code:

```
@FindBy(id="listAccounts")
WebElement accountDropdown;

public void selectAccount(){
    logger.info("Selecting Account");
    implicitwait(10);

    Select dropdown = new Select(accountDropdown);
    logger.info("Drop down is multiple::"+ dropdown.isMultiple());
}
```

Expected:
Code should execute completely even when separated code page wise.

Actual:
When I have all pages code in one test class, code executed.
But when I place them separately in page wise test class, element not found exception is thrown.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"listAccounts"}
```

Comment: I can't tell from your limited code and your chart if you're implementing pageobject factory properly.  Do you pass a driver object from your test class to the pageobject class, and do you call the base pageobjectclass super, passing it the driver to initialize the page objects?

Comment: @BillHileman ** I am passing the driver object to Instantiate Page Object using Page Factory but i am not passing driver as i am not using the Constructors in my classes as i did not see the need of it for passing the driver object to super class because I have a Utility/Helper class called Browser  which have a singleton method to return browser object any where its called. I have kept the Page Factory initialize as first statement in side the TestNG Test method it self and i am assigning it globally **

Comment: When i debugged,the PageObject has to be initialized first and then the methods to be called, but , it seems that object is not getting initialized and so the element not found exception is thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In POM using PageFactory framework, one should initialise PageFactory in Constructor of PageClasses.  Please find below code snippet which might work in your case.

```
public class LoginPage extends TestBase {

public LoginPage() {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);//Here driver is initialised in TestBase class and inherited in LoginPage class
}
//your code

@FindBy(id="listAccounts")
WebElement accountDropdown;

public void selectAccount(){
logger.info("Selecting Account");
implicitwait(10);
Select dropdown = new Select(accountDropdown);
logger.info("Drop down is multiple::"+ dropdown.isMultiple());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A complement to the Krishna answer:

```java
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
```

The code above can be moved to the base class and from the LoginPage, you just pass the webdriver on the constructor like this.

```java
public class LoginPage extends Base {

public LoginPage(Webdriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}
...
```

```java
public class Base {

public Base(Webdriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
...
```